# Continuously replenished reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Substrate ($m$) concentration in a reaction scheme is governed by the equation $$\frac{dm}{dt} = -\dfrac{r_1c_1m}{1+\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}m + \dfrac{r_1r_3}{r_2r_4}m^2}$$ where $c_1$ is the initial enzyme concentration and each $r_i$ is the reaction rate of the reactions present within this reaction scheme (which are positive). Now additionally suppose the substrate is being continuously replenished by a reaction $$\ce{A->[r_5]S,}$$ where $A$ has constant concentration $a_0$. Modify $dm/dt$ and show there are two distinct positive equilibria $0<m_1<m_2$ if $r_5<r_5^C$ where $r_5^C$ is a critical value to be determined.

---

With this information we have

$$\frac{dm}{dt} = -\dfrac{r_1c_1m}{1+\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}m + \dfrac{r_1r_3}{r_2r_4}m^2}+r_5a_0.$$

Equilibria when $dm/dt=0$. We rearrange this to produce the quadratic

$$r_2r_4r_5a_0 + r_1r_4(r_5a_0 - r_2c_1)m + r_1r_3r_5a_0m^2=0$$

So the equilibria occur at

$$m_{1,2} = \dfrac{r_1r_4(r_2c_1-r_5a_0)\pm\sqrt{r_1^2r_4^2(r_5a_0-r_2c_1)^2-4r_1r_2r_3r_4r_5^2a_0^2}}{2r_1r_3r_5a_0}$$

Now I need to justify these are positive and find the critical value for $r_5$ but I have no idea how to continue here.

Comment: If i am following you, $m$ is the substrate concentration. So $m = r_5a_0$ which is substituted into your first equation.

Comment: $m$ is the substrate concentration but I have not made that substitution

Comment: How did you get from your equation 1 to your equation 3 ?!?

Comment: I have added $r_5a_0$ to the rate of change for concentration of the substrate as it is being increased by $a_0$ at reaction rate $r_5$. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You have $\ce{A->[r_5]S}$ which means the concentration of S is given by $r_5$ times the concentration of A. In the first sentence you wrote "Substrate ($m$) concentration" so $m$ is the concentration of S.

Comment: Sorry for having mislead you. I totally misinterpreted the part "Now additionally suppose the substrate is being continuously replenished by a reaction..." and my answer was totally wrong so I deleted it. No sense confusing some other poor soul with nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe the way we solved the equation for the discriminant equal to zero.  You and I both did the same thing.  All we really needed to do is solve $R^2-\lambda = 0$ by writing $R^2=\lambda$, and taking the square root of both sides.  The resulting equation is then linear in r5.

Anyway, if I did the algebra correctly, I get the double root as:
$$m_1=m_2=\sqrt{\frac{r_2r_4}{r_1r_3}}$$
So, I guess one has to conclude that, in order to guarantee that the roots are  different, we have to take as the critical value of $r_5$ the value that we determined by setting the discriminant equal to zero.

Comment: When you square root both sides why do we take $R>0$, i.e. $R = +\sqrt{\lambda}$ over $R = -\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Comment: For the same reason we said before.  That's the only way to guarantee a positive r5.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to set the discriminant equal to zero, and thereby solve for the critical value of $r_5$. When I did this, I got $$r_5a_0=\frac{r_2c_1}{1+2\sqrt{\frac{r_2r_3}{r_1r_4}}}$$.  The next step is to substitute this into the equation for m, and find the two  corresponding equal values of m.

Comment: Actually it's not.  All that's required is a little more mathematical manipulation.  Factor out the $r_2c_1$ and, in the denominator, use the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: Yes.  I left out the 2.  Thanks.  I'm going to go back and correct it.   We choose the negative numerator because that choice will guarantee that the answer is always positive.

Comment: Also replace all the $\ge$ signs with $>$ signs.

Comment: I like what you did much better than what I was suggesting.  Very nice reasoning.

Comment: Which would be the correct answer in the end then?

Comment: Your result is the correct bound.  My result is consistent with your more general relationship, but it has no deeper meaning than that.  All it does it tell you at what value of r5 the two roots are equal.

Comment: @ChesterMiller - I assume you started with  $$\frac{dm}{dt} = -\dfrac{r_1c_1m}{1+\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}m + \dfrac{r_1r_3}{r_2r_4}m^2}+r_5a_0.$$

Comment: Yes, that is the starting equation.